# avoiding duplicate column error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been trying to figure out why I get a duplicate column error when adding a column to a mysql DB using php but it's confusing me.

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES from $tbl_name";
$result = $conn2->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $test = $row[$i];
        $sql2 = "ALTER TABLE $test ADD COLUMN abc VARCHAR( 255 )";
        $result2 = $conn2->query($sql2);
        if ($conn2->query($sql2) === TRUE) {} else {echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn2->error;}
    }
}
```

This code works and adds a column to each table, however it give error output like this:

```
Duplicate column name 'abc'Error: ALTER TABLE hyft ADD COLUMN abc VARCHAR( 255 )
Duplicate column name 'abc'Error: ALTER TABLE ibgk ADD COLUMN abc VARCHAR( 255 )
Duplicate column name 'abc'Error: ALTER TABLE ihrd ADD COLUMN abc VARCHAR( 255 )
Duplicate column name 'abc'Error: ALTER TABLE imc ADD COLUMN abc VARCHAR( 255 )
Duplicate column name 'abc'Error: ALTER TABLE intn ADD COLUMN abc VARCHAR( 255 )
```

So my question is why does it think there are duplicate columns and how to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have already a column named `abc`?

Comment: Why do you want to add a column abc to your table from php code?

Comment: The error message seems to require no additional explanation

Comment: You're running the query twice:
1) $result2 = $conn2->query($sql2)
2) $conn2->query($sql2) === TRUE

Comment: @AYR this sounds like the answer, I will test in the morning. Still new to this and make simple mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly based on the hint from AYR it is seeming that way… spent hours trying to write the code different ways with no luck. Hopefully tomorrow is a better day :)

Comment: I suggest you configure your database library to just throw exceptions on error. Checking manually not only is annoying but can lead to silly errors like this as well.

Comment: @AYR this was indeed the problem, everything is error free now, thank you! If you want to submit an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález in my eyes the database is already throwing exceptions, please explain if you can, I would like to try different methods.

Comment: I mean [PHP exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). This way you don't need `if ($conn2->query($sql2) === TRUE)`.